# how to create fcl project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

can any one tell me how to run the examples problems given in jfuzzylogic library using eclipse. I installed all needed plugin in eclipse and I download the jfuzzylogic jar file. I don't know how to proceed further. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use jfuzzylite instead. It is free and open source. It does not require third-party libraries, contains more features than jfuzzylogic (except for parameter optimization), the binary size is less than 300KB, and the user interface with qtfuzzylite is very easy to use. Visit www.fuzzylite.com.